# OutOfMemory Error: Bitmap exceeds VM Budget while creating Bitmap

Tags: android, android-layout

I am painting using `MyView` here. Sometimes when I open the activity, I am getting an OutOfMemory Exception Bitmap size exceeds VM Budget in MyView `onSizeChanged()`. Please does anyone have a suggestion for me?

Here is my code:

```
private Paint mPaint; 
private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Canvas canvas;
public class MyView extends View
{
    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mBitmapPaint;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
         mPath = new Path();
            mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);            
        canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);  
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    public void clear(){
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(480, 480, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mPath = new Path();
        invalidate();
    }

    public void destroy() {
        if (mBitmap != null) {
            mBitmap.recycle();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if(action)
        {
            invalidate();
        }

        int swidth=(int)(6*(screenWidth/1024));
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        //mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(swidth);

        int swidth1=(int)(3*(screenWidth/1024));
        Paint painto = new Paint();
        painto.setAntiAlias(true);
        painto.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.magnata));
        painto.setStrokeWidth(swidth1);
        painto.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        xstart=(int)(15*(screenWidth/1024));
        xend=(int)(1010*(screenWidth/1024));
        ystart=(int)(90*(screenHeight/600));
        y1end=(int)(550*(screenHeight/600));

        canvas.drawLine(xstart, ystart, xend, ystart, painto);  
        canvas.drawLine(xstart, ystart, xstart, y1end, painto);
        canvas.drawLine(xstart, y1end, xend, y1end, painto);
        canvas.drawLine(xend, ystart, xend, y1end, painto);

        Paint p1=new Paint();

        p1.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        p1.setAntiAlias(true);

        Paint p2=new Paint();
        p2.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bcolor));
        p2.setAntiAlias(true);

        float swidth3=(int)(120*(screenWidth/1024));

        float swidth4=(int)(4*(screenWidth/1024));
        p1.setTextSize(swidth3);
        p2.setTextSize(swidth3);

        Paint p3=new Paint();
        p3.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        p3.setStrokeWidth(swidth4);
        p3.setAntiAlias(true);
        p3.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/KINDTRG.TTF"); 
        Typeface font2=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/KINDB.TTF");
        p1.setTypeface(font);            
        p2.setTypeface(font);

        int xline1=(int)(15*(screenWidth/1024));

        int xline2=(int)(500*(screenWidth/1024));
        int yline1=(int)(5*(screenHeight/600));
        int yline2=(int)(85*(screenHeight/600));

        canvas.drawLine(xline1, yline1, xline2, yline1, p3);
        canvas.drawLine(xline1, yline2, xline2, yline2, p3);


        float width11=(int)(5*(screenWidth/1024));


        float width22=(int)(20*(screenWidth/1024));
        Paint paint9=new Paint();
        paint9.setStrokeWidth(width11);
        paint9.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray));
        paint9.setAntiAlias(true);
        DashPathEffect dashPath = new DashPathEffect(new float[]{width22,width22}, (float) 5.5);

        paint9.setPathEffect(dashPath);
        paint9.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        float width121=(int)(2*(screenWidth/1024));
        Paint paint2=new Paint();
        paint2.setStrokeWidth(width121);
        paint2.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint2.setTextSize(15);
        paint2.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

        float width131=(int)(6*(screenWidth/1024));
        float textsize22=(int)(17*(screenWidth/1024));
        Paint paint1 = new Paint();

        paint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint1.setStrokeWidth(width131);
        paint1.setTypeface(font2);
        paint1.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint1.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint1.setTextSize(textsize22);

        int xtextl=(int)(65*(screenWidth/1024));
        int ytext1=(int)(107*(screenHeight/600));

        canvas.drawText("Say  the  words  that  start  with  the  short   a   sound .", xtextl, ytext1, paint1);


        int ytext2=(int)(228*(screenHeight/600));
        int ytext3=(int)(340*(screenHeight/600));
        int ytext4=(int)(359*(screenHeight/600));

        canvas.drawText("Circle  the  pictures  that  start  with  the  short   a   sound.", xtextl, ytext2, paint1);
        canvas.drawText("Say the name of each picture to help you determine the beginning sound.", xtextl,ytext3,paint1);
        canvas.drawText("  Press the tennis ball with the correct answer to spell the word.", xtextl, ytext4,paint1);


        Paint p=new Paint();
        int xcir1=(int)(65*(screenWidth/1024));
        int xcir2=(int)(1010*(screenWidth/1024));
        int xcir3=(int)(10*(screenWidth/1024));

        float rad=(int)(2*(screenWidth/1024));
        int ycir1=(int)(212*(screenHeight/600));
        int ycir2=(int)(323*(screenHeight/600));
        p.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.magnata));

        for(int i=xcir1;i<xcir2;i+=xcir3)
        {
            canvas.drawCircle(i, ycir1, rad, p);
        }
        for(int i=xcir1;i<xcir2;i+=xcir3)
        {
            canvas.drawCircle(i, ycir2, rad, p);
        }  

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint); 
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 2;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        Log.i("me.getRawX()",""+ event.getRawX());
        Log.i("me.getRawY()",""+ event.getRawY());

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I am getting an error inside `onSizeChanged()` on the line below:

```
mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Comment: what is the size of the bitmap you're trying to load? Usually stuff with more than 1000px by 1000px WILL be out of memory, not matter how much optimisation you try to do.

Comment: i dnt knw the size the bitmap i did nt mention in my code.but i run app in 1024/600 tablet.if possible see my code once

Comment: You should not instantiate new objects in your `onDraw()` method... This won't solve your problem I suppose, but it will decrease the user experience as the GC will kick in at some point.

Comment: ok.then how to instantiate new obj in my onDraw().i use gc also but no use

Comment: Place `mPaint = new Paint();` in the constructor of your class an use `mPaint` for all painting activities you do. Instead of creating a new Paint instance for each painting activity! Did you disable LINT? As it you warn you about this!

Answer (score 0):

If your bitmap is very big, or at least if you free application memory is nearly exhausted, the new bitmap does not fit in the application memory anymore, due to the old bitmap which is still present (until the garbage collector dropped by and freed it)

You might be able to solve your problem by (explicitly) freeing the memory of the old bitmap first.

Using the [recycle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29) method:

```
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
  if(mBitmap != null) {
    // Explicitly free memory of old bitmap
    mBitmap.recycle();
  }
  mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);            

  // Rest of code
}
```

You might want to do the same in your `clear()` method.

Comment: Then, I guess, the dimensions of your bitmap are simply too large (in comparison with your applications free memory)... Or you are leaking memory somewhere...

Comment: ok. thnku.but i did give any dimensions to bitmap.if leak memory in some where means why in tis method i am getting that exception.

Comment: You are getting the exception in this method, because it requires a huge chunk of memory, which is not available anymore due to the leaks (if this is the problem). The location of your (potential) leaks is somewhere else.

Comment: You use 20 instances of the class you have given, that all create a 1024x600 bitmap? I suppose you have found your problem...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18057/discussion-between-user1089640-and-veger)